# How do I use a generic class without specifying its type parameters in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, generic-type-argument

I'm aware that multiple similar sounding questions have been asked before, however I still believe that this particular problem has not been solved yet.

There is a class `Super` and a generic class `Foo<T> : Super`, which both come from a third-party library. I need to extend the functionality of `Foo<T>` so I have this generic class:

```cs
public class Bar<T, U> : Foo<T> {
  public void DoSomething() { ... }

  // Other things that use T and U
}
```

I now want to have a collection(list) of "Bar's" and be able to call DoSomething on all of them. So logically, I dont care about the type argument of Bar, when calling the void method as it is irrelevant in that scenario.

Additionally the third-party library exposes methods such as:

```cs
public LibraryMethod(Super super) { ... }
```

And I need to be able to call that method with any of my "Bar's".

###### Not-A-Solution 1: Interfaces

The reason why I cant use an interface is, because the third-party library expects a `Super` in some of the methods it exposes, and an interface can be implemented by any class, so I cannot use my Bar's as Super's even though every Bar (no matter what its type arguments are) must be a Super. The interface essentially ruins the inheritance chain here and I can no longer pass my "Bar's" to methods expecting a Super.

###### Not-A-Solution 2: Non-Generic Base Class

Obviously I cannot make `Bar<T, U>` inherit from a non-generic base class, as per the same reason as above. It would ruin the inheritance chain as well.

## Fictional Ideal Situation

In an ideal situation I could do something like this:

```
List<Bar<>> bars = new List<Bar<>>();

bars.Add(new Bar<Type1, Type2>());
bars.Add(new Bar<Type3, Type4>());

foreach (Bar<> bar in bars) {
  bar.DoSomething();
}

LibraryMethod(bars[0]);
```

Comment: Why can't you declare an interface like `public interface IBar { void DoSomething(); }` and then use it like `foreach (IBar bar in listy) { bar.DoSomething(); }`

Comment: As I have stated in "Not-A-Solution 1", I need to be able to later pass my "Bar's" to the third-party library methods, which only accepts Foo's. And an interface would break this contract.

Comment: Well, probably won't cast correctly, `foreach (var x in listy) { var bar = x as IBar; }` but the question still stands

Comment: Well, you can always cast it to a different type, so that still doesn't explain why an interface won't work. Maybe you can post some more code to explain your problem better.

Comment: @BurnsBA I have adjusted the question and clarified some of the context as I wrongfully simplified the problem.

Comment: Do `DoSomething` and `LibraryMethod` *really* need to know the types of `T` and `U`?

Comment: Where is `LibraryMethod()` declared? It is important because you might be able to take advantage of the automatic type parameter resolution the compiler offers for methods.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. All `Bar<T,U>` derive from `Foo<T>` which derive from `Super`. So you call `LibraryMethod(Super super)` with all the bars. Please explain what the problem is.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou OP wants list that has two types restrictions (`MyList<T, R1,R2>where T:R1, T:R2`) that supports iterating over "the list" as `IEnumerable<R1>` and `IEnumerable<R2>`... but due to the fact that C# is not Java they have problem even adding those items to initial list, but currently focusing on calling methods from both types... (that's how I see the question).

Answer (score 1):

In short - you can't, C# does not support instantiating instances of open generic types and you can't limit the list to be both `Super` and `IDoSomething` interface at the same time. And you can't inherit `Bar` from some non-generic type (which inherits `Super` and implements `IDoSomething`) and `Foo<>` in addition.

In this particular case you can add `AsSuper` to your interface:

```cs
public interface IDoSomething
{
   void DoSomething();
   Super AsSuper();
}
```

Which should be easily implemented in `Bar`:

```cs
public class Bar<T, U> : Foo<T>, IDoSomething {
  public void DoSomething() { ... }
  public Super AsSuper() => this;
  // Other things that use T and U
}
```

Which will allow you to type safely invoke `LibraryMethod`:

```cs
LibraryMethod(bars[0].AsSuper());
```

Comment: This seems very promising, as it basically solves the inheritance chain problem by turning the "is-a" into a "can-be-made-into-a". Very clever!
Currently checking whether or not this really solves my problem...

Comment: @TheHelpfulHelper note that this approach has a caveat - if `LibraryMethod` mutates the argument and `AsSuper` implementation would return something else (for example new instance - `new Super(...)`) the behavior of the system can be faulty.

Comment: Ahh of course there is a catch. Well I suppose any code can be faulty if the programmer isn't paying attention to what their doing. But this is good to point out. I still think this is the best solution to the problem so far.

Comment: This has indeed solved my problem. However I think the original question as stated in the title is not solved by this. But instead this is a work around to the impossibility of the original problem. So I should update the question title and mark this as the answer?

Comment: @TheHelpfulHelper you really can't change question at this point as there are answers that address other parts... Keeping question as-is probably ok. I would not add more to it as it long enough already :)

Comment: @TheHelpfulHelper updated answer a bit so it is more inline with question.

Comment: @TheHelpfulHelper no new ones) if awnser works for you - you can mark it as accepted one until a better one arrives.

Answer (score 0):

You can lose type information at compile time and track this elsewhere. Maybe you have program knowledge (you, the programmer) and know type information. Otherwise you have to create some data structure and carry this information around. Anyways, you can use interfaces here.

Consider your current situation (does not work):

```cs
public class Super { public int SuperData { get; set; } }
public class Foo<T> : Super { public T FooData { get; set; } }
public class Bar<T, U> : Foo<T>
{
    public U BarData { get; set; }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i do something");
    }
}

public static void LibraryMethod(Super super) { Console.WriteLine("i'm super"); }
public void Main()
{
    // generic "object" collection
    var listy = new List<object>();
    listy.Add(new Bar<int, double>());
    listy.Add(new Bar<DateTime, bool>());
    
    foreach (var x in listy)
    {
        x.DoSomething(); /// 'object' does not contain a definition for 'DoSomething'

        // and then call your library
        LibraryMethod((Super)x);
    }
}
```

Instead, add an interface and implement in your type:

```cs
public interface IDoSomething
{
    void DoSomething();
}

public class Bar<T, U> : Foo<T>, IDoSomething
{
    public U BarData { get; set; }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i do something");
    }
}
```

Now you can use with cast to correct interface type:

```
public void Main()
{
    var listy = new List<object>();
    listy.Add(new Bar<int, double>());
    listy.Add(new Bar<DateTime, bool>());
    
    foreach (var x in listy)
    {
        var bar = x as IDoSomething;
        // check null reference
        bar.DoSomething();

        // and then call your library
        LibraryMethod((Super)x);
    }
}
```

output:

```
> Main()
i do something
i'm super
i do something
i'm super
```

Comment: This only works, as long as you are being careful not to implement IDoSomething on a class that doesn't inherit from Super. Otherwise the cast will throw an exception at runtime. Therefor this is type-unsafe and kind of misses the point of a strongly typed language such as C#

Comment: Er, what, you asked about how to implement a method that didn't use anything from a base class? But that's not how interfaces work, if your type implements the interface then it will cast.

Comment: Youre doing a (Super)x cast. x is-a IDoSomething. If I make a new class "Buz" and make it implement IDoSomething and create an instance "buz" of that class then I cannot do (Super)buz as Buz does not inherit from Super. That would be an illegal cast afaik.

Comment: ah, right, sure, so check for null reference the same as you should two lines above. This answer is just a guide. If you need to bend guidelines to accomplish some goal you're going to have to figure out the safe way to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do what you describe.
replace your bar class by List or KeyValuePair to see what it result in:

```
var myList = new List<List<>>(); 
var myListOfKv = new List<KeyValuePair<>>();
```

you are trying to allocate some memory, the compiler needs to know some constraints.
you can maybe try to put some restrictions on types like:
class Bar<x,y> :Foo where x is ISoda

you might also think of another way to extend functionnality by adding in your children specific method to handle objects:

```
class Bar<x>: Foo<x>
{
    public void Inject(Iy iy);
    public void UseInjected();
}
```

The third party lib will still accept the Bar instances and ignore new functionnality.